# Graph theory - Minimum number of edges to be removed

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, trees

Given a tree of $n$ nodes. Each node has some weight associated with it. Find the minimum number of edges to be removed from the tree such that for all the newly formed trees (When we remove an edge, a new tree will be formed.), sum of all the weights of the nodes in each tree must be at most $K$ (Total weight $\le K$)?

**Attempt:**$\;$(pasted from the OP's comment)

Approach, I've tried is, I did post order traversal and found the weight of all subtrees. if subtree weight exceeds $K$, then I'll separate that subtree by removing an edge. Again, I need remove few edges in that tree to make sure the subtrees weigh less than $K$. I did this by sorting all child nodes in descending order according to weight of each child subtree and removing few subtrees as long as the tree weighs more than $K$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you looking for efficient algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for effecient algo

Comment: Approach, I've tried is, I did post order traversal and found the weight of all subtrees. if subtree weight exceeds K, then I'll separate that subtree by removing an edge. Again, I need remove few edges in that tree to make sure the subtrees weigh less than K. I did this by sorting all child nodes in descending order according to weight of each child subtree and removing few subtrees as long as the tree weighs > K

Comment: @user3223196: To avoid having your question closed for lack of context, you should edit your post so as to include your ideas and attempts in the post itself, not just in a comment.

Comment: Actually, the OP did provide context in a comment. Was such a quick close action really justified?

Comment: @user3223196: Lesson for the future: MSE can be a pretty unfriendly place! On the other hand, it can be a very valuable resource if you play the game intelligently. To avoid downvotes and votes to close, always provide context (e.g., your ideas or attempts) as part of the original post, as opposed to posting just the question.

Comment: If the graph is complete, this is the knapsack problem.

Comment: @Empy2 If the graph is both complete and a tree, the problem is still not hard

Comment: @Hagenvoneitzen :)

Comment: @Empy2, how is this knapsack problem? Can you provide explanation?

Comment: I forgot the tree structure, but you are looking for subsets of the nodes that sum to less than $K$